# How to make dashed, twodash and solid lines in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the dataframe below and I have three lines which I want to change to (Dashed, Twodashe and solid) lines in ggplot:

```
df <- structure(list(Time = structure(c(147L, 25L, 44L, 20L, 7L, 74L, 
51L, 156L, 62L, 115L), .Label = c("06:00:00", "06:05:00", "06:10:00", 
"06:15:00", "06:20:00", "06:25:00", "06:30:00", "06:35:00", "06:40:00", 
"06:45:00", "06:50:00", "06:55:00", "07:00:00", "07:05:00", "07:10:00", 
"07:15:00", "07:20:00", "07:25:00", "07:30:00", "07:35:00", "07:40:00", 
"07:45:00", "07:50:00", "07:55:00", "08:00:00", "08:05:00", "08:10:00", 
"08:15:00", "08:20:00", "08:25:00", "08:30:00", "08:35:00", "08:40:00", 
"08:45:00", "08:50:00", "08:55:00", "09:00:00", "09:05:00", "09:10:00", 
"09:15:00", "09:20:00", "09:25:00", "09:30:00", "09:35:00", "09:40:00", 
"09:45:00", "09:50:00", "09:55:00", "10:00:00", "10:05:00", "10:10:00", 
"10:15:00", "10:20:00", "10:25:00", "10:30:00", "10:35:00", "10:40:00", 
"10:45:00", "10:50:00", "10:55:00", "11:00:00", "11:05:00", "11:10:00", 
"11:15:00", "11:20:00", "11:25:00", "11:30:00", "11:35:00", "11:40:00", 
"11:45:00", "11:50:00", "11:55:00", "12:00:00", "12:05:00", "12:10:00", 
"12:15:00", "12:20:00", "12:25:00", "12:30:00", "12:35:00", "12:40:00", 
"12:45:00", "12:50:00", "12:55:00", "13:00:00", "13:05:00", "13:10:00", 
"13:15:00", "13:20:00", "13:25:00", "13:30:00", "13:35:00", "13:40:00", 
"13:45:00", "13:50:00", "13:55:00", "14:00:00", "14:05:00", "14:10:00", 
"14:15:00", "14:20:00", "14:25:00", "14:30:00", "14:35:00", "14:40:00", 
"14:45:00", "14:50:00", "14:55:00", "15:00:00", "15:05:00", "15:10:00", 
"15:15:00", "15:20:00", "15:25:00", "15:30:00", "15:35:00", "15:40:00", 
"15:45:00", "15:50:00", "15:55:00", "16:00:00", "16:05:00", "16:10:00", 
"16:15:00", "16:20:00", "16:25:00", "16:30:00", "16:35:00", "16:40:00", 
"16:45:00", "16:50:00", "16:55:00", "17:00:00", "17:05:00", "17:10:00", 
"17:15:00", "17:20:00", "17:25:00", "17:30:00", "17:35:00", "17:40:00", 
"17:45:00", "17:50:00", "17:55:00", "18:00:00", "18:05:00", "18:10:00", 
"18:15:00", "18:20:00", "18:25:00", "18:30:00", "18:35:00", "18:40:00", 
"18:45:00", "18:50:00", "18:55:00", "19:00:00"), class = "factor"), 
    variable = structure(c(3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 
    2L), .Label = c("Ground Speed(km/h)", "Precipitation(cm/h)", 
    "Predicted Speed(km/h)"), class = "factor"), value = c(105.507629394531, 
    101.367, 105.266487121582, 3.0613, 99.758, 106.194, 101.367, 
    106.969375610352, 107.803, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
```

I used the following code to make the plot but I couldn't make the required lines:

```
ggplot(df.m, aes(x=Time, y=value, group = variable))+geom_line()+
  scale_x_discrete(breaks=c("07:00:00","10:00:00","13:00:00", "15:00:00", "18:00:00"),
                   labels=c("7:00", "10:00", "13:00", "15:00", "18:00"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `scale_linetype_manual` after specifying `linetype=variable` :

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(x=Time, y=value, group = variable, linetype=variable))+
   geom_line() +
   theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1)) + 
   scale_linetype_manual(values=c("dashed", "twodash", "solid"))
```

[image]